# Playwright & NodeJs - Read CSV and push data to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, web-scraping, playwright

I am using the **playwright** library for web scraping and URLs are stored in a CSV file. I am trying to read the CSV file and pick the URLs in an array to utilize in the scraping code.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
// Support    
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

// Array to store the URL.
var urls = [];
// This prints an empty array.
console.log(urls);

fs.createReadStream('sample.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
    // Trying push the URL in the array
    urls.push(row);

    // This prints the values of URLs
    console.log(urls);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
  });
// Here I don't see the URLs but an empty array.
console.log("URLS:" + urls);
```

In the method ".on('data'" the value gets pushed to the array and the console is also printing those, however, post-execution when I try to get the URLs from the array it returns an empty array.

Comment: The variable name is in caps where you are doing the console.log in the end. That's why it's empty.

Comment: I tried with everything, however, the result was still the same. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is written assuming that links are the only thing that are in your CSV file.

```
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');
const fs = require("fs");

// Reads the CSV file and saves it  
var links = fs.readFileSync('Path/to/csv')
    .toString() // convert Buffer to string
    .split('\n') // split string to lines
    .map(e => e.trim()) // remove white spaces for each line

// Start of for loop, to loop through csv file
for (const link of links) {
    // Normal test set up for playwright. adding the + link.toString to avoid duplicate test name error
    test('test for ' + link.toString(), async ({ page }) => {
        // First csv file item sent to console
        console.log(link);
        // Goes to that csv link item
        await page.goto(link);
        // Do whatever else you need
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Edited. hope that is enough info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code will extract the data from csv file and store it in a String array. Then we can use `ArrayName[1]`, `ArrayName[2]` to get the actual values.

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

// Array to store the csv values.
var kpis : string[] = [];

kpis= fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/Public/Documents/KPIValues.csv')
  .toString() // convert Buffer to string
  .split('\n') // split string to lines
  .map(e => e.trim()) ; // remove white spaces for each line;

console.log("All Data:" + kpis);
console.log("First row:"+ kpis[1]);
```